# How to run drush with cron (elysia cron)?

Tags: 7, drush, cron

**Problem**

I can't get cron (specifically elysia cron) to run with Drush. I've been using [this](http://drush.ws/docs/cron.html) as a guide. What have I missed/done wrong?

**My Crontab**

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
COLUMNS=80

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/drush @main elysia-cron
* * * * * env > /tmp/cronenv.log
```

Checklist:

- I've used *www-data* for my crontab. This is the default nginx server user.
- The path to drush (`/usr/bin/drush`), comes from `which drush`.
- I've used an alias for the site, @main. I've tested this outside of cron and the command `drush @main elysia-cron` runs cron, although only once an hour (see [this problem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95978/using-a-drush-alias-with-elysia-cron-alias-permission-missing)). This cron runs every five minutes so it should work once an hour.

I also tried the format in the docs above:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/env PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin COLUMNS=80 /usr/bin/drush @main elysia-cron
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be easier to use `--root` and `--uri` instead of `@main`.  Drush loads aliases on a per-user basis; the user you are testing `drush @main elysia-cron` probably has the `@main` alias defined in an alias file in `~/.drush`.  You'd need to either move your aliases to a global location, or perhaps copy your alias file to the www-data user's `.drush` folder.

Comment: Cheers for third time in a row Greg, I did indeed have my alias file defined for a user who wasn't `www-data`, I'd completely forgotten I'd moved it from sites.

Answer (score 0):

I copied my aliases drush folder from `~/.drush` to `/var/www` the home of the default server user: `www-data`.

The command in Ubuntu I used was:

```
cp -r ~/.drush /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drush --root=/var/your website/ elysia-cron
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. This may be an answer, but it does not explain why or how. Could you add some detail to it?

Answer (score 0):

Just make bash script
/var/www/scripts/elysia_cron.sh

```
cd /var/www #put your path to the document root which add centext  
/usr/bin/drush elysia-cron
```

and start this script on cron

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/scripts/elysia_cron.sh
```