# Cron Run error for drush update script

Tags: cron

I have created a script drup.sh to update the site with security issues and placed it in the sites/default dir.

```
#!/bin/bash
drush up drupal --security-only -y
```

And on testing it by running bash drup.sh from the command line, as the user, in the sites/default dir. all works good

When I set up a cron to run it, as the user, I get the following errors

```
Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will       [error]
need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
this command.
Command pm-update needs the following modules installed/enabled to       [error]
run: update.
The drush command 'up' could not be executed.                            [error]
A Drupal installation directory could not be found                       [error]
```

The command I use at the moment is

```
bash /home/user/public_html/sites/default/drup.sh
```

---

I have looked at the page you suggested, I had looked at it before but it did not make sense to me. I have tried various combinations, without success

The closest I can get to it not giving an error is

```
/usr/bin/env PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin COLUMNS=72 --username=/home/username/public_html/sites/default/drup.sh
```

the output is

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
USER=middlesex
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
REMOTE_ADDR_PROTOCOL=4
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
SERVER_REALROOT=/usr/libexec/webmin
PWD=/usr/libexec/webmin/cron/
PERLLIB=/usr/libexec/webmin
REMOTE_ADDR=x.x.x.x
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/username 
LOGNAME=username
_=/usr/bin/env
COLUMNS=72
--username=/home/username/public_html/sites/default/drup.sh
```

But drush does not run or do anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run drush with cron (elysia cron)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96093/how-to-run-drush-with-cron-elysia-cron)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look what is said [here](http://www.drush.org/en/master/cron/) about running drush with crontab and pay especially attention to "Setting the PATH". Also you should specify the path to your drupal installation with the --root option.